# React Native : Huge memory usage and lack of responsiveness

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-router

I'm developing an app using react-native (V0.34) and after pushing some components using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) module the memory usage has increased  and the app is lagging ... 
I've inspected the view hierarchy using Xcode and here is the screenshot.

[image: Xcode debug view hierarchy]
How could i reduce the memory usage and eliminate those empty RCTView ?